# Actual process for fractions to decimals?

Tags: arithmetic

Alright. I want to get a fraction into decimal. Without a calculator.

> $\frac{15}{7} = 2.14285714$

Basically, what are the steps for *manually* getting that decimal result?

Comment: Do you know how to do long division?

Comment: fraction sometimes rdenotes ratio ( of integers) or sometimes fractional part ( of real number )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ordinary long division:

```
   2.1428571...
 --------------
7)15.0000000...
  14
  ---
   1 0
     7
   ---
     30
     28
     --
      20
      14
      --
       60
       56
       --
        40
        35
        --
         50
         49
         --
          10
```

and so on. Note that this remainder of $10$ repeats an the earlier one, so the whole cycle will repeat: the quotient is $2.142857142857142857\dots$.

Comment: +1 for the sheer effort of typesetting that long-division :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try standard box form long division like you were taught to divide integers and decimals in elementary school.

Also these numbers are rational so they will always terminate or repeat.

Comment: How do you know what he was taught in elementary school in these days of hand-held calculators?

Answer (score 1):

I have a java class I wrote for java that represents rational numbers using the Bignteger class for the numerator and denominator. Besides basic operations, it also includes an instance method for converting to a repeating decimal and a static method for the reverse converson. Here they are:

```
public String toRepeatingDecimalString()
{
    if (den.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
        return num.toString();
    BigInteger d = new BigInteger(den.toString());
    long pow2 = 0;
    long pow5 = 0;
    BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
    BigInteger five = new BigInteger("5");
    BigInteger ten = two.multiply(five);
    while (d.mod(two).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        d = d.divide(two);
        pow2++;
    }
    while (d.mod(five).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        d = d.divide(five);
        pow5++;
    }
    long nonrep = Math.max(pow2, pow5);
    String decimal = num.abs().divide(den).toString() + ".";
    if (num.signum() < 0) decimal = "-" + decimal;
    BigInteger rem = num.abs().mod(den);
    for (long i = 0; i < nonrep; i++) {
        rem = rem.multiply(ten);
        decimal += rem.divide(den).toString();
        rem = rem.mod(den);
    }

    if (!rem.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        BigInteger stop = new BigInteger(rem.toString());
        decimal += "[";
        rem = rem.multiply(ten);
        decimal += rem.divide(den).toString();
        rem = rem.mod(den);
        while (!rem.equals(stop)) {
            rem = rem.multiply(ten);
            decimal += rem.divide(den).toString();
            rem = rem.mod(den);
        }
        decimal += "]";
    }
    return decimal;

}
```

and

```
public static Fraction fromRepeatingDecimalString(String repDecStr)
{
    int index = repDecStr.indexOf('.');
    if (index == -1)
        return new Fraction(new BigInteger(repDecStr), BigInteger.ONE);
    else {
        int sign = 1;
        if (repDecStr.startsWith("-"))
            sign = -1;
        BigInteger intPart = (sign == 1 ? new BigInteger(repDecStr.substring(0,index)) :
                              (new BigInteger(repDecStr.substring(1,index))).negate());
        String fpart = repDecStr.substring(index+1);
        BigInteger TEN = new BigInteger("10");
        index = fpart.indexOf('[');
        if (index == -1) {
            BigInteger d = TEN.pow(fpart.length());

            if (sign == 1)
                return new Fraction(intPart.multiply(d).add(new BigInteger(fpart)),d);
            else
                return new Fraction(intPart.multiply(d).subtract(new BigInteger(fpart)),d);
        }
        else {
            if(!(fpart.endsWith("]")))
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            String nonrep = fpart.substring(0,index);
            String rep = fpart.substring(index+1,fpart.length()-1);
            BigInteger part1 = TEN.pow(nonrep.length());
            BigInteger part2 = TEN.pow(rep.length()).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
            BigInteger full = part1.multiply(part2);
            if (nonrep.equals(""))
                nonrep = "0";

            if (sign == 1)
                return new Fraction(full.multiply(intPart).add(part2.multiply(new BigInteger(nonrep)))
                                    .add(new BigInteger(rep)),full);
            else
                return new Fraction(full.multiply(intPart).subtract(part2.multiply(new BigInteger(nonrep)))
                                    .subtract(new BigInteger(rep)),full);

        }
    }
}
```

The fraction is reduced to lowest terms by the class constructor.